# Fetch and append element at last using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div parent element with class .carousel-inner. Within this parent div, there are some children elements. I want to take its 2nd (child) element and append that element at last. I am getting and appending second element like this.

```
var a = $(".carousel-inner").children()[1];
$(".carousel-inner").append(a);
```

Now as I append this element, it removes this element from second position and append at the last. I want to keep this element a the second position as well. How can I do it?

Comment: use clone() as in my answer below . let me know if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `clone()` after you find the element. and make another variable

```js
var a = $(".carousel-inner").children()[1],
    b = $(a).clone();
$(".carousel-inner").append(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="child">
    a
    </div>
      <div class="child">
    this clones
    </div>
      <div class="child">
    c
    </div>
</div>
```

OR clone the element just before appending like so :

```js
var a = $(".carousel-inner").children()[1]
$(a).clone().appendTo('.carousel-inner');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="child">
    a
    </div>
      <div class="child">
    this clones
    </div>
      <div class="child">
    c
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad i could help.  :d

Comment: Can you tell me, how to append at start?

Comment: @UmairJameel use `prepend` or `prependTo` instead of `append` or `appendTo`

Answer (score 2):

Use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$(a).clone().appendTo('.carousel-inner');
```

Comment: It is giving an error that clone is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `clone()`;

```
var a = $(".test").children()[1];
a = $(a).clone();
$(".carousel-inner").append(a);
```

Comment: It is giving an error that clone is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Clone is the good way to achieve what you want :

```
var a = $(".carousel-inner").children().eq(1);
a.clone().appendTo('.carousel-inner');
```

you are receiving an error because  `$(".carousel-inner").children()[1]` get the DOM object and `$(".carousel-inner").children().eq(1)` get the Jquery object
and clone is defined only on jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

use clone function like beolw
 $("p").clone().appendTo("body");

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do this way also.

```js
var a = $(".carousel-inner").children().eq(1).prop('outerHTML');
$(".carousel-inner").append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class"first-child">First</div>
 <div class"second-child">Second</div>
  <div class"third-child">Third</div>
  <div class"fourth-child">Fourth</div>
</div>
```